# How to execute both if and else blocks based on a condition into if-statement block?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a script like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["LoginValidation"]) && $_SESSION["LoginValidation"] == 1){

    $something = $db->prepare('SELECT cookie FROM users WHERE id = ?');
    $something->execute(array($_SESSION["Id"]));
    $num_row = $something->fetch();
    $_SESSION["cookie"] = $num_row['cookie'];

    if ( $_SESSION["cookie"] != $_COOKIE['login']) ){
        // jump to following else statement (outer else statement)
    }

} else {
    /* here - this block should be execute when
         - That inner if-statement is true
         OR
         - That outer if-statement is false
    */
}
```

As you see, I need to execute `if`-statement and if inner `if`-statement is `true` then execute `else`-statement. How can I do that?

Comment: Change the condition and put the code into the if statement which you want to execute it when they are equal.

Comment: @Rizier123 Well I cannot do that *(based on my real codes)* .. Actually I need a *"jump"* or *"go to"* code *(or something similar)*

Comment: Is the else necessary for the 1st if?

Comment: By definition you cannot jump to within the else if you're already within the if. This is good scenario to use an include or a function to ensure you don't replicate code.

Comment: @NicholasKajoh Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a algorithm problem and not php. Anyway, there are several ways to do. For example:

```
$innerCondition = false;
$outerCondition = false;

if(isset($_SESSION["LoginValidation"]) && $_SESSION["LoginValidation"] == 1) {
    $outerCondition = true;
    // ...

    if ($_SESSION["cookie"] != $_COOKIE['login']) {
      $innerCondition = true;
      // ...
    }

} 

if ($innerCondition || !$outerCondition) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: You only need 2 `if`s. The 2nd one would say `if (!$validated || $validated && $_SESSION...)`.

Comment: @stack Look at this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$doElse = true;
if(isset($_SESSION["LoginValidation"]) && $_SESSION["LoginValidation"] == 1){

    $doElse = false;
    $something = $db->prepare('SELECT cookie FROM users WHERE id = ?');
    $something->execute(array($_SESSION["Id"]));
    $num_row = $something->fetch();
    $_SESSION["cookie"] = $num_row['cookie'];

    if ( $_SESSION["cookie"] != $_COOKIE['login']) ){
        $doElse = true;
    }
    else {
        //rest of the logic
    }

} 

if ($doElse) {
    // here - this block should be execute when inner if-statement is true
}
```

Comment: Wrong .. `if ($doElse) {` also should be execute when outer `if`-statement is *false* (like an `else` for it)

Comment: Under what condition will `doElse` be false?

Comment: @stack So you do, or don't want the else condition to execute on the if?  Please be clear, as your above statement contradicts your question.

Comment: @Daedalus I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @stack We don't understand what you're asking; that's the point here.  You need to clarify your question.  For example, right now your question states that an else is executed if the result is true or false..  Not one or the other.  This would mean that the statement is executed no matter the result, so there is no reason for an additional if statement.  So again, please clarify.

Comment: @Daedalus Look, that `else` should be executed in two cases: 1. outer `if` is *false*, 2. inner `if` is *true*.

Comment: @stack. `if($doElse)` in my example *will* be executed when the first `if` will be false. Just before it `$doElse` is set to true. First command when first `if` is true resets `$doElse` to false so it won't be executed unless inner `if` is true.

Comment: @stack That isn't how php works.  You'll need to set a variable to the result of the inner if, and another to the outer if, then compare both results in a separate if.